# How to exclude a jar from eclipse class path?

Tags: eclipse

How to modify the xml to exclude a jar name which is added to the classpath ? (this jar belongs to other project which the project that I run depends on)
how to modify .classpath file?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the .classpath file and remove the corresponding entry.. .classpath file is hidden and is inside the root directory of your eclipse project.

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="path-to-jar"/>
```